# RSS feed to email

Tags: email, rss

a newbie on RSS feed here. I need to monitor a RSS feed via the email. I have tried the rss2email(http://www.allthingsrss.com/rss2email/). But it seems sometimes doesn't work properly for some reason. I noticed, it didn't send email when there's a new RSS feed. I'm not very familiar with phyton, but I see a pattern when one of the RSS feed doesn't have a link, it seems got confused.

I'm wondering do you guys know any good free tools to convert the RSS feed into a email or what is the simplest way to do it? The RSS feed i need to monitor is RSS 2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for scipts, you have

- [feeds2imap](http://bitgarten.ch/projects/feeds2imap/)
- [newspipe](http://newspipe.sourceforge.net/) (Python)
- [rss2mail](http://exo.org.uk/code/rss2mail/) (Python)

Otherwise, web services like the follwing are doing a pretty googd job
- MailChimp (RSS campaigns, free until 2000 subscribers)
- Zapier
- IFTTT

Comment: Thank you so much Serge! These are really useful! Will look into it.